# Parallel for loop and reading files that will be used in multiple threads, best practice?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, readfile

I'm creating an application where I want to rename a bunch of files in a bunch of folders based on the content of an xslx file.

I'm making a parallel for loop where each folder get's it's own "thread" (or whatchamacallit), the application should then, based on the folder name, retrieve all the posts in the xlsx file with the corresponding folder name and rename the contents of the folder based on what it got from the xlsx file. I hope this makes sense.

My question is: When should I read the xlsx file? As I see it I have two options: 1) Open the file *before* the parallel iteration and have each iteration loop through the file's contents looking for the folder name. Possible issues could be that multiple threads will be checking the same array simultaneously. I don't know if that could fudge stuff up. 2) Open the file once for *each* iteration and loop through to find results. I'm thinking that opening the file multiple times would instead be more time consuming than it has to be.

The xlsx file has about 48000 rows of data.

EDIT:

I've dropped the parallel for loop and gone with a regular one due to comments and answers advising me to and explaining why. But I'll leave it in the question for others to find.

The question is now: When should I open the xlsx file? (for details see pre-edit)

Comment: Are all the folders on the same physical disk?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: Are you sure it's worth starting a parallel thread for every folder then - chances are you're going to be waiting on disk IO a lot...

Comment: The relative speed between CPU processing an hard drive activity is several orders of magnitude different. By using multiple threads you might save 1 millisecond for every 1 seconds of actual work. It's not worth it. In fact, simultaneous disk access can cause massive seek times and actually make your program much much slower.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure. I'm self-taught as a programmer so I don't really have all the basics, my knowledge is scattered at best. I've been learning stuff as I go along and as any certain work project needs something. So what does "wait for disk io" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use multithreading for I/O bound operations. Even if you use really fast storage device such as SSD or RAID, you would not get much performance boost from multithreading. For regular HDDs the performance would actually get worse. Try copying multiple files or extracting multiple zip archives simultaniously, for example. You will quickly notice the performance drop, due to multiple threads constantly fighting over single I/O device.

Comment: Aha! I get it! Thanks for the tip, I never thought of this actually. I basically thought multithreading = faster always.

Comment: @ChristopherSirén, as a rule of a thumb: mulithreading = faster computation (CPU bound operations). There are a few exceptions, ofc.

Answer (score 1):

I ran some tests to see what kind of performance improvement you might get, if any. I decided to create 10,000 files and, using `Stopwatch`, time how long it took to rename the files. I used a single-threaded and multi-threaded approach.

Here's the code:

```
//var path = @"D:\Users\Enigmativity\Temporary\SOTest"; //HDD
var path = @"C:\_temporary\SOTest"; //SSD
var files = 10000;
var format = "00000";

var rnd = new Random();
Enumerable
    .Range(0, files)
    .OrderBy(n => rnd.NextDouble())
    .ForEach(n => File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, n.ToString(format) + ".txt"), n.ToString()));
```

I then ran this:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Enumerable
    .Range(0, files)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(n =>
        System.IO.File.Move(
            System.IO.Path.Combine(path, n.ToString(format) + ".txt"),
            System.IO.Path.Combine(path, n.ToString(format) + n.ToString(format) + ".txt")));
sw.Stop();
```

And compared it to this:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Enumerable
    .Range(0, files)
    .GroupBy(x => 10 * x / files)
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll(ns =>
        ns
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(n =>
                System.IO.File.Move(
                    System.IO.Path.Combine(path, n.ToString(format) + ".txt"),
                    System.IO.Path.Combine(path, n.ToString(format) + n.ToString(format) + ".txt"))));
sw.Stop();
```

At the end of each run I cleaned up the files:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).ForEach(x => File.Delete(x));
```

My results were:

```
Single thread on HDD: 2,155 milliseconds
Multi-threads on HDD: 1,601 milliseconds

Single thread on SSD: 2,457 milliseconds
Multi-threads on SSD: 940 milliseconds
```

I ran these results numerous times and each run was roughly the same time. I got a huge benefit from the SSD running in parallel and a moderate benefit on a HDD.

Comment: You could experiment with different DOPs. The ones that the TPL chooses are usually asinine and not suitable for IO either.

Comment: Degree of parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Just reading from a data structure is safe to do concurrently. This is not an issue here. The issue I see is that if you don't perform any preprocessing on the list you will scan it many times from many threads which is a waste. What about this:

```
var excelItems = ...; //Fill this in.
var groupedbyFolder = excelItems.GroupBy(x => x.directoryName);
groupedByFolder.AsParallel().ForAll(g => ProcessFolder(g));
```

This traverses the data just once and is very easy clean code.

You need to configure `AsParallel` to an empirically determined degree of parallelism as well. Try different values.

Comment: I'd like to say that I get this answer but I don't. At all. (Self taught programmer) The xlsx file is already grouped by folder name. If that is a part of what you're asking. What i gather from your answer is that maybe I should loop through the xlsx file, instead of the array of folders, and check if that particular folder is meant to be processed and then process? That would be just one thread, and I need this to be a speedy operation. Although renaming usually is.

Comment: You want to process one folder at a time right? ("where each folder get's it's own "thread""). You should run a parallel loop of some form over a set of folders. That's the last line of this answer. How you produce that set of folders does not really matter. I have made an example here of how I thought your data looks like but apparently I was wrong at that guess.

Comment: Regarding parallel speedup, different hardware has different parallelism. Even magnetic disks can benefit from it because there's parallelism at the filesystem layer and one physical IO can rename multiple files (sometimes). Also disk accesses become more efficient if sorted by physical location. SSDs have real hardware parallelism. Your update says you have dropped parallelism which is a mistake if you didn't measure it. The other answer is not correct in general and assumes very favorable conditions for its reasoning to work.

Comment: So I *should* go with parallel iterations?

Comment: It's probably a plus. It's so easy to implement that you probably should do that and measure different DOPs including 1.